Could you proofread my diary?
Date: 20th Oct 2024
Title: I Eat A Lot
Nowadays, I am very worried to have a lot dinner.
When having a lot dinner, I am too tired and lazy to do something to studying English.
I knew these negative effect. but, it was hard to improve it beacuse of environment of my place.
My mom is good at cooking. so, I had a dinner each time, I couldn't resist temptation of delicious food.
I should tell my mom not to cook a lot. Hahaha..
